# C# List of different classes

Tags: c#, list, class, base-class

I did not find the answer in searching for it.

I need a List that contains different classes, each of them inherent from a base class `BaseA`, but each of them will have properties others will not have, or some that uses the same class will.

```
public class BaseA
{
    public int ID = 0;
}

public class AA : BaseA
{
    public int AID = 0;
}

public class AB : BaseA
{
    public int BID = 1;
}

public class AC : BaseA
{
    public int CID = 0;
}
```

Now the question is how do I get a single List that may contain class AA,AB and AC and the editor will not think i'm only working with one of them.

I tried to made the `List<BaseA>`, but this will only expose the bassA properties, and what i need is like to be able to do `List[0].AID` where it will understand what AID means if i'm talking about the AA class.

I may be going it all wrong, can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: It sounds as if you have a design flaw. Go back a step and decide if you should even have a shared list for these classes

Comment: You may be right, but the shared list for those classes is a better solution then 9 lists to go trough.

Comment: Maybe not if you have to have 9 different ways to extract the data from that single list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using *Linq* for this:

```
  List<BaseA> list = ...

  var result = list
    .OfType<AA>() // Filter out AA instances only
    .ElementAt(0) // or just First();
    .AID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for casting, perhaps?

```
var list = new List<BaseA>
{
     new AA(),
     new AB(),
     new AC(),
}

var aa = list[0] as AA;

if (aa != null)
{
    var id = aa.AID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would need to place a variable or property in the base class that stores what type it is then attempt a cast (List[0] as AA) and if it doesn't return null use the newly cast object to select the desired variable.

The real question is why do the derived classes need their own ID variable, especially if you are throwing them in a list based on said ID.

Comment: The ID and AID or BID is just a example ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible way to do this simply and elegantly. Provide an abstract method in your base class (or multiple of them):

```
public abstract void AID(parameters);
```

And in each of the classes override that method to do a particular thing related to that class.

Or you can take an alternative way; check for each object if it's the type of each of the classes:

```
if(obj is AA){
//do AA stuff
}
if(obj is AB){
//do AB stuff
}
if(obj is AC){
//do AC stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways you can try,

1. going with your approach, cast the item in the list to `((AA)List[0]).AID`.

You should have some knowledge of the object that it belongs to `AA` in order to access the property `AID` on it.

if your requirement is limited to the usage that you've described then I would suggest that you have something in similar lines provided below

```
class BaseA
{
    public string ObjectType { get; set; } //enum would be a good choice.

    public int ID { get; set; }
             (or)
    public Dictionary<string,int> AllProperties { get; set; }
}
```

With this approach, you can check the type of the class and call appropriate property on it.

Comment: A cast will not work, as i got to cast it to many times around.
I also tried the enum way to find out what type it was before some code, but i was thinking there must be a better way to do it.