# Adding different types of objects/variables to a single List in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic class defined as:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
   // some properties
}

public class CustomClass {
   // some properties
}
```

I have three instances of these classes defined as follows:

```
MyClass<int> instance1 = new MyClass<int>();
MyClass<string> instance2 = new MyClass<string>();
MyClass<CustomClass> instance3 = new MyClass<CustomClass>();
```

Also I have to store some primitive types

```
string s1 = "My string";
int i1 = 5;
```

How do I create a single list that can contain all the above variables?

Comment: `List<object>`?

Comment: Hi maybe this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658539/c-sharp-list-of-different

Comment: Of course, why would you want to store different types in the same list? That's not a common method and resorts in some nasty code later on.

Comment: `List<object> totals = new List<object>(); totals.AddRange(instance1); totals.AddRange(instance2); totals.AddRange(instance3);` is easiest way to do this since all classes in C# are based on `object`.

Comment: @DavidG: Asking this out of curiosity is all :)

Comment: @goutham_kgh please accept one of these answers if it helped to solve your problem, as this will be useful for other people with the same issue to see the answer that helped you solve your issue. Otherwise, please provide more information to allow others to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can find a common interface for each of the three types and create that, you would be able to make a `List<IMyClass>` that would take all three.

You can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) to find out more about interfaces.

As long as `MyClass<T>` implements that interface, then the list would accept them all.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
var myList = new List<object> {instance1, instance2, instance3};
```